# A tool to generate run time recursive call tree

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

Is there an easy tool to generate run time call tree for a recursive algorithm? Such as the following one for computing Fibonacci number :

[image: call tree for computing Fibonacci number]

More specificly,what if the algorithm is implemented in C/C++?

EDIT:I want this tree to analyze the complexity of a recursive algorithm.I know how to generate the tree in hand. Previously I just add some "cout" in soure file and generate a dot file and use graphviz to generate the tree.But I want to know if there was some good tools so I can save my time of writing the code.

EDIT:An example code for Fibonacci number is

```
//fib.cpp
#include<iostream>
typedef int Int;

Int fib(Int n)
{
  if (n==0)
    return 1;
  else if (n==1)
    return 1;
  else
    return fib(n-2)+fib(n-1);
}

int main()
{
  std::cout<<fib(5)<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I have tried valgrind for this simple code but can't find how to get the graph.The command I used is as follow:

```
g++ fib.cpp
valgrind --tool=callgrind ./a.out
kcachegrind callgrind.out.4343
```

Did I miss some options or what ?

Comment: isnt it depth first algorithm?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

Comment: [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: @pmg.I don't how to use Valgrind to get what I want.Can you explain it.

Comment: Hmmm @luoq --- that's a tougher question: I don't know. But valgrind does everything one can wish for. I'm sure there is a way to extract the data you need from one of the reports produced with it.

Comment: @pmg.Thanks for your reply.I will try to search out if valgrind can do this.

Answer (score 6):

Use callgrind (cmdline) and then kcachegrind (gui) to visualize call trees. It's one of the tools from the 'valgrind' suite.

Callgrind is a profiling tool which also allows you to see the complete call tree. You collect the profiling info by running it on your program, then you analyze the output of the callgrind info with kcachegrind.

Additional edit: Unfortunately as i just found out this will work only *partially* for recursive calls which will in this case look like a stub calling itself multiple times. Even though callgrind will do a dynamic call graph it fails here at showing the passed and returned values. A static callgraph tool will have the same output (without the amount of times called).

This will look like this, not what you want:

[image]

I guess the only way to find out in which sequence and with which parameters and return values the recursive function has been called is to do a backtrace (gdb or the backtrace() function) and visualize that output (via graphviz). There are tools for that but as far as i know not freely available/open source.

Comment: If you're on a linux system it's quite straightforward to install and use. Windows might need a little more effort.

Comment: Please see the EDIT for my problem.

Comment: I've tried to get the calling tree for your code but Callgrind will give you a usable calling tree only for non-recursive functions. So you end up seeing how many times and from where your function has been called (itself, 13x) but not the parameters and return values. The latter is what you need since you want to see all passed parameters and return values which form leafs and nodes of the tree. So callgrind is only of partial help here. After all it's a profiling tool (you can find out how much time you spend in your calls and how many you had but not in which sequence).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.It seems no easy tool available now.I will just add some code in the source file to get the information.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a tool as such, but you can manually create the tree (and then print it however you like it. For that particular algorithm, a tree node would be something like:

```
struct node {
   int value;
   int result;
   node *left;
   node *right;
   node( int value ) : value(value), result(), left(), right() {}
};
```

And then you can modify the function to allow it to construct the tree:

```
int fibo( int value, node*& ptr )
{
   ptr = new node( value );
   ptr->result = fibo( value-1, ptr->left ) + fibo( value-2, ptr->right );
   return ptr->result;
}
```

Intially call it like:

```
node* tree;
fibo( 5, tree );
```

And then work on the tree that you have built.

Comment: I want to know if there is already some tools so I don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a tree and store a reference to the active leaf.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "obtain run time call tree"?
You want to obtain a list of calls in some array?

If you want to get a list of all calls at runtime, you can simply create those functions and print something in each of them (or add to a vector or whatever), e.g:

```
int fib(int i) {
  int ret;
  printf("fib(%d)\n",i);
  if (i>2) ret=fib(i-2)+fib(i-1);
  else ret=i;
  printf("fib-end(%d)\n",i);
}
```

If you want to obtain something similar but at compile time, you can try the following approach:

```
template <int i>
inline int fib() {
  //do something
  return fib<i-2>()+fib<i-1>();
}

template <>
inline int fib<0>() {return 0;}

tempalte <>
inline int fib<1>() {return 1;}
```

In the latter case, the fibonacci number will be computed at compile-time, so all function calls will be expanded and constants collapsed, resulting in a code that will evaluate in constant time.

Comment: see my edit for what I want.The fib is just an example,I want to handle a more complicated code or any recursive code.I want the tree in a graph or anything that can represent the tree.